# Why I can't detect ANY iBeacons using Swift while Objective C can?

Tags: swift, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

So, I've been working to detect available iBeacons in my office. I surfed the internet and always found a solution where you NEED to know the UUID of the iBeacons in order to detect it. However, I found this on [github](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/AnyiBeacon-iOS) (shout-out to this guy). I ran this app in my office and it was able to detect 2 available iBeacons (1 of them have dynamic UUID) but it was written in objective C.

How is it possible that on objective c, it can detect surrounding iBeacons while Swift can't?

I guess this is the `Objective C`'s code to start scanning for iBeacon (I never learned obj c before):

```
AIBBeaconRegionAny *beaconRegionAny = [[AIBBeaconRegionAny alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Any"];
[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegionAny];
```

And this is my code in Swift:

```
locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "Any")!, major: 9, minor: 2)).
```

Well, it crashed of course, I also changed it to `"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"` and print the beacon but didn't find any.

Can anyone explain what did I miss? Or is it actually possible now?

Thank you in advance

UPDATE:

There's `AIBBeaconRegionAny` which also made it possible to detect any beacon.

File `AIBBeaconRegionAny.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AIBBeaconRegionAny : CLBeaconRegion

- (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@end
```

File `AIBBeaconRegionAny.m`:

```
#import "AIBBeaconRegionAny.h"

// https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CLRegion.h
struct ClientRegion {
    BOOL identifier[512];
    BOOL onBehalfOfIdentifier[512];
    int type;
    bool notifyOnEntry;
    bool notifyOnExit;
    bool conservativeEntry;
    union {
        struct {
            BOOL proximityUUID[512];
            unsigned short major;
            unsigned short minor;
            int definitionMask;
            bool notifyEntryStateOnDisplay;
        } beaconAttributes;
        struct {
            struct {
                double latitude;
                double longitude;
            } center;
            double radius;
            double desiredAccuracy;
            int referenceFrame;
        } circularAttributes;
    } ;
};

@interface CLBeaconRegion (Hidden)

- (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (struct ClientRegion)clientRegion;

@end

@implementation AIBBeaconRegionAny

- (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
{
    return (self = [super initWithIdentifier:identifier]);
}

- (struct ClientRegion)clientRegion
{
    struct ClientRegion clientRegion = [super clientRegion];
    
    // definitionMask:
    //                  1 => uuid
    //                  3 => uuid + major
    //                  7 => uuid + major + minor
    
    clientRegion.beaconAttributes.definitionMask = ~0x07;
    
    return clientRegion;
}

@end
```

Comment: It's calling deprecated method `startRangingBeacons(in:)`, not `startRangingBeacons(satisfying:)`. Also, it's using custom class `AIBBeaconRegionAny`, which has some rules, because it's inherits from `CLBeaconRegion` instead with a custom init. I guess that `clientRegion.beaconAttributes.definitionMask = ~0x07;` is important. Which isn't present in your code.

Comment: What is `AIBBeaconRegionAny` do actually? Also, what `AIBBeaconRegionAny.m` creating there? Is it possible to create something like that in Swift and able to detect any iBeacon around? @Larme

Comment: I guess it's "hacking" little private API `CLRegion`, making it "visible", since after all it's not possible by default, and not recommended in the guidelines/doc. I don't know it that trick is replicable with no deprecated ranging method. Might needs a check. Else, you can import Objective-C code into Swift, so why not doing so?

Comment: Do u mean like combining the Objective-C code with Swift? I'm actually work in SwiftUI, is that possible to combine it?

Comment: That's just classes, there shouldn't be an issue. But as said, since it seems to use private API it might then no be suitable for the AppStore (and got rejected for that reason).

Comment: I see. I think that's the only problem if I want to upload it in the app store. Btw, thanks for responding mate, giving me better ideas.